# FCM Cordova Plugin - Send Notification to Non-Subscribed User

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I don't understand very well how to send a notification to a user that receives an action. For example, when `User A` adds a comment or a like to `User B`, I want `User B` to receive a notification.

If `User A` adds a comment or a like, I can send a notification to each follower that is subscribed in the topic of `User A` in this mode. Topic subscription by followers:

```
FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic('topicExample');
```

And I send a notification by the REST API by `User A`:

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification title",  //Any value
    "body":"Notification body",  //Any value
    "sound":"default", //If you want notification sound
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",  //Must be present for Android
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"  //White icon Android resource
  },
  "data":{
    "param1":"value1",  //Any data to be retrieved in the notification callback
    "param2":"value2"
  },
    "to":"/topics/topicExample", //Topic or single device
    "priority":"high", //If not set, notification won't be delivered on completely closed iOS app
    "restricted_package_name":"" //Optional. Set for application filtering
}
```

But I don't understand how to send a notification to `User B`, because he is **not subscribed** to `User A` and is it possible to send the notification only to users subscribed to a certain topic?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the scenario you want is that for `User B` to receive a notification from `User A` even if he's not subscribed to `User A`'s topic? If yes, I just don't see the sense in this question. If you want `User B` to receive the notifications from `User A`, why not just subscribe?

Comment: because the user B is the receiver of the action. an example. if the user  A add a comment to the photo of the user B. all follower of the user A can receive a notification because they are the followers and are subscribed to the user A news but the user B not necessarily is a follower of user A, he just receive a comment by user A but he does not follow him.

Comment: In that scenario, I think you need to send a two separate requests. One for the subscribers and one for the receiver of the action.

Comment: how can i send to single device? how can i know what is the device of the receiver

Comment: You have to use the corresponding registration token.

Comment: yes you mean the device registration id. but i not understand how other users can know this ID. is a good idea to store it in the database? Furthermore i think that there are the danger that other users can use this ID to spam in the user device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124529/discussion-between-al-and-dthink).